# 500 Internal Server Error after install Magento 2.4.2 on windows

Tags: magento2.4.2

getting 500 internal server error while installing Magento 2.4.2 community edition.
configured virtual hosts and given right directory paths but getting same 500 internal server error.

and after removed htaccess,  css& js is not redirecting to pub static folder.

---

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/7.4.27 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

Comment: Can you share the log error from var log ?

Comment: Enable php errors